# Racket Error: Expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments

Tags: racket, dr.racket

Sorry, I just started using racket. I'm pretty new at this. I've written this piece of code:

```
(define (save_sheets lst num)
  (if(= num (- (length lst) 1))
     ('())
     (
      (my_save_image (join_sheet (list-ref lst num)) num)
      (save_sheets lst (+ num 1)))))
```

Of course, when I run this I get this error:

```
application: not a procedure;
expected a procedure that can be applied to arguments
given: (object:image% ...)
arguments...: [none]
```

`(join_sheet (list-ref lst num))` should return an image, which the error shows, but the `my_save_image` should take it in right? It's parameters is the image and a number. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that parentheses in Racket (and other Lisp-like languages) are not like parentheses in other languages… they are important! In many languages, there is no difference between `x`, `(x)`, `((x))`, and `((((x))))`, but in Racket, these are all very different expressions.

In Racket, parentheses mean *function application*. That is, `(f)` is like writing `f()` in other languages, so `((f))` is like writing `f()()`, and so on. This is important, since it means things like `(3)` are quite nonsensical in Racket—that would be like writing `3()` in other languages, and `3` is definitely not a function.

Now, let’s consider the problem you’re having. You are using `if`, which has the following grammar:

```
(if conditional-expression then-expression else-expression)
```

This means that each of the pieces of code inside the `if` must be valid expressions on their own. However, take a close look at your *`then-expression`*, which is `('())`. This is kind of like the `(3)` example from earlier, isn’t it? `'()` is not a function, so it should not be surrounded in parentheses!

Your *`else-expression`* exhibits a similar problem, but it is a little more complicated, since you seem to wish to run two functions there. If you want to run the first function for side-effects, you would not use parentheses alone for grouping, you would use [`begin`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/begin.html#%28form._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._begin%29%29), but it’s not clear to me if that’s what you actually want here or not. In any case, as-written, your program will attempt to *apply the result of the call to `my_save_image` as a function*, passing it the result of the recursive call to `save_sheets` as an argument, which is almost certainly not what you want.

Mind your parentheses. In Racket, they are to be treated with care.

Comment: My problem was sort of like your answer, except it was what join_sheet was returning. I put extra parenthesis there. Thanks!